# bash how to get var from file with multiple lines

Tags: bash

I have two files, the first contains a series of names :

```
CONTAINER1
CONTAINER2
CONTAINER3
CONTAINER4
```

And the second script runs when the sintaxis is ./script.sh CONTAINER1

```
 CONT=$1
 PID=`opmnctl status -noheaders -fmt %prt30%pid7R  | grep -w $CONT | awk '{print $3}'`

 netstat -anp | grep $PID | grep ESTABLISHED > $CONT-temp
```

Is it possible to run the second script by parsing each line of the first file?. I'm new at bash, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: well actually its a small part of a bigger script, what it matters to me is how can i achieve that, basically with that command i get the established connections from a container of my application server..

Comment: FYI, it's conventional to use lower-case names for variables which aren't either (1) shell built-ins, or (2) exported to the environment. Also, as a correctness issue, your second script should be quoting its expansions -- so `grep "$pid"` rather than `grep $pid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xargs for this: it reads words from its stdin and appends them to the given command. Normally it takes several parameters at a time so it invokes the given command as few times as possible, but you can control that with the `-L` option:

```
xargs -L 1 echo "name is:" < containers.txt
```

produces

```
name is: CONTAINER1
name is: CONTAINER2
name is: CONTAINER3
name is: CONTAINER4
```

You would write

```
xargs -L 1 ./script.sh < containers.txt
```

Comment: you've make my day buddy...it was just what i needed